# Don't want to bring all features on the staging branch to master

Tags: git, continuous-integration, devops, branching-and-merging, cherry-pick

So our team always pushes code to the staging branch for our management to test the website.
And we used to work on a branch like this:

```
Feature branches -> Develop -> Staging -> Master (production)
```

The Develop, Staging, and Master are configured with CI, automated deploy to each environment server.

And once we finish our features and reach the staging branch, some of the features we developed and committed to staging are not ready yet to bring/merge to master, only some of the features are we want to merge to master (production).

For instance, management still testing or the test for certain features is taking longer.

How do we solve a problem like this?
I have read about `git cherry-pick`, but is it good for this scenario?
Or do you have any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider maintaining an internal release branch and keep that separate to your master one. Doing so allows everybody to merge their changes into the master branch at their convenience while not disrupting the branch used to build the internal release for testing. This creates a bit of extra work because you'll now have to synchronise your internal release branch with master at milestone points.

Comment: @miqh you mean, create another branch and server environment just for developers?

Comment: Essentially, yes. However, I'd think of it the other way around: you're creating another branch and CI environment for internal release. IMHO, the master branch should always contain the latest changes from everybody. Whether it means master is always stable is your call. Treat the internal release branch as snapshots of master.